# get data from server with jquery ajax in android phonegap

Tags: android, codeigniter, rest, jquery, cordova

hi i am developing an app for android (use phonegap, html5 and javascript) which connect itself to a remote mysql-database. 
i created a RESTful (codeigniter) web services to access the mysql database, then the Android app can call the web service to get or post data to the db, using XML or JSON as the format of data.

In web browser using jquery ajax I am succesfully getting the result but in android app not getting the response.

```
jQuery.ajax({
url : 'http://10.10.1.129/index.php/apiauth/auth/?'+jQuery("#form-login").serialize(),
async :true,
cache :false,
/*crossDomain : true,*/
dataType : 'jsonp',
success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    }  
});
```

in server :

```
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
    class Apiauth extends REST_Controller
    {
        function auth_get()
        {
            $this->load->model('mauth');
            $username   = $this->input->get('username') ? $this->input->get('username') : $this->get('username');
            $password   = $this->input->get('password') ? $this->input->get('password') : $this->get('password');
            $auth       = $this->mauth->getUserLogin('*',$username,$password);
            $row        = $auth->row();
            if($row){
                $data   = array('username'=>$row->username, 'fullname'=>$row->fullname,'error'=>FALSE);
            }else{
                $data   = array('error'=>true);
            }
            $this->response($data, 200);
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any Android code here at all...?

Comment: ups i'm sorry i use phonegap, html5 and javascript for developing android apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you added an access origin with the ip address specified in the ajax request? This file is located in your application-dir/res/xml/config.xml localhost is allowed by default but you need to add other hosts when using. So your config.xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<cordova>
    <!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin="http://10.10.1.129*"/> <!-- allow requests from your server -->


    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="org.apache.cordova.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

Comment: Phonegap appears to have only started paying attention to this setting sometime after version 2.3.0. I had the entries specified by josh but included a spelling mistake in the domain name. All worked fine under Cordova/Phonegap 2.3.0.


When I upgraded to V2.7.0, the AJAX would call the success function however the response was always null. When I corrected the spelling mistake - bingo all worked again.


I found the subdomains="true" element to be particularly useful as we have to allow for the domain name with or without the 'www' as is suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`<access origin=".*"/>` didnt worked at all, we must put specific url that we call during ajax request.

`<access origin="http://10.10.1.129"/>` this worked.