# Phonegap Android download data from remote server jsonp

Tags: php, android, cordova, jsonp

Testing downloading data from remote Db using Phonegap Android and JSONP

Works perfectly in Browser (with php file on remote host and index both from localhost on my local machine and when on remote host) and in Ripple but zero data displaying when ported to Android via Phonegap..just the 'Details' text is displaying..no error..

My code :

```
**INDEX.html**
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>json</title> 
<script src="phonegap3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/
1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var output = $('#output');

$.ajax({

url: 'http://mydomain.com.com/landmarks1.php',

dataType: 'jsonp',

jsonp: 'jsoncallback',

timeout: 5000,

success: function(data, status){

$.each(data, function(i,item){

var contact = '<p>'+item.name+'</p>'

+ '<p>'+item.address+'</p><hr>';




$("#mylbl").append(contact);

});

},
error: function(){

output.text('There was an error loading the data.');

}

}); 

});

</script>   


</head> 
<body> 
<div>
Details

<span id="mylbl"></span>


</div>   

</body> 
</html>


**landmarks1.php**

<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

mysql_connect("localhost","m560847_sean","1994martha");
mysql_select_db("m560847_contacts");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact");

$records = array();
echo mysql_error();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$records[] = $row;
}

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

I've given access to remote domain in my xml file

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
<access origin="http://mydomain.com.com*" />
<access origin=".*"/>
```

I've looked at many many similar issues on here and in general on web and am stumped..

Comment: could you post in error appear for you ?? and i recommend to don't use CDN Lib in phoneGap

Comment: No error appears in android...just no data displays..blank screen except for the 'details' tag

Comment: why you using jsonp if you allow cross domain access ?

Comment: Just learning and following this tutorial http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/

Comment: are you add plugin NetworkStatus ??

Comment: No could you explain please?

Comment: add plugin that will help you to make bridge between the hardware Like wifi and Js code   like permission in android 

take look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676241/get-data-from-server-with-jquery-ajax-in-android-phonegap

Comment: Ok are you saying that I need to add the network plugin to enable Internet or network access for my app? I haven't seen that ANYWHERE online...this is driving me crazy - i've tried every solution I can find and no resolution

Comment: yea , till you can making remote request for your data

Comment: OK I'll try and report back - just to be sure we're talking about https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git??

Comment: Tried that....still no luck...thought I may have found solution in that I hadn't added allow sub domains but still no luck...

Comment: are you still using CDN  in your code ?

Comment: Ag sorry missed your CDN comment earlier..yes I am...how would that do anything other than slow app load time?

Comment: CDN put me in problem using  phonegap try to use offline file it may help you in problem

Comment: OK not using CDN this time...still no data displayed but did get error message, for firs time, saying 'There was an error loading the data'..mad stuff...Im sure this is an issue lots of people have starting out?

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with your domain whitelisting. Try setting the domains only to <access origin="*"/>. Then try to restrict the whitelists if it works. As it is now, you should probably remove the trailing * from the domains.

Comment: Finally....FINALLY sorted this one..domain whitelist of "*" works - I had ".*" there instead.....so ok it works but now gotta figure out why mydomain whitelisting fails......thanks all (especially ville0